# PineScript alert() for strategy issue

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hellow dear scripters

i have a question.

in my custom strategy i am having issues with the closing trade condition alert. my current open trade allert is working ok but the exit strategy i am having issues with declaring a exit condition, because my exit conditions are inside the (strategy.exit and strategy.enter)

here is a part of my code:

```
// Specify Entry Conditions
longEntry = fanUpTrend and bullishPinBar and bullPierce
shortEntry = fanDnTrend and bearishPinBar and bearPierce

// Long Entry Function
enterlong() =>
    risk = usr_risk * 0.01 * strategy.equity
    stopLoss = low[1] - atr[1] * atr_mult
    entryPrice = high[1]
    units = risk / (entryPrice - stopLoss)
    strategy.entry('long', strategy.long, 2000, units, stop=entryPrice)
    strategy.exit('exit long', from_entry='long', trail_points=20, trail_offset=10)


// Short Entry Function
entershort() =>
    risk = usr_risk * 0.01 * strategy.equity
    stopLoss = high[1] + atr[1] * atr_mult
    entryPrice = low[1]
    units = risk / (stopLoss - entryPrice)
    strategy.entry('short', strategy.short, 2000, units, stop=entryPrice)
    strategy.exit('exit short', from_entry='short', trail_points=20, trail_offset=10)

long_open_message = input('Long Open Message')
short_open_message = input('Short Open Message')
long_close_message = input('Long Close Message')
short_close_message = input('Short Close Message')


// Execute Long Entry
if longEntry
    enterlong()
    alertsyntax_golong = long_open_message
    alert(message=alertsyntax_golong, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

// Execute Short Entry
if shortEntry
    entershort()
    alertsyntax_goshort = short_open_message
    alert(message=alertsyntax_goshort, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

so here i can easyly get an alert for the entry but my exit conditios are, inside the strat enter and strat exit how can i declare a variable or function to be able to send alert like :

if shortEntry
alert()......

type of code.

What i am trying to achieve is that i need to declare somekind of variable to be able get define the strategy.exit and also my "units" in the strategy.enter and also "stop=entryPrice"
thanks again

Comment: Why do you not use the strategy alerts directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can place alert messages as a parameter: (See PineScript language reference manual: strategy.close(id, when, comment, qty, qty_percent, alert_message) → void

I assume you want to pass a variable value via the alert message?

For that, you would use the command: str.tostring(variable). You must place the argument in inverted commas and + signs in order for your code to compile.
Here is an example:
strategy.close('ATV_LE', alert_message='"pair":"ETHUSDT","signalId":"long-ETHUSDT","exchange":"binance","exchangeAccountType":"futures","side":"long","type":"exit","orderType":"market","positionSizePercentage":"**'+str.tostring(variable)+'**"')

See the Pine Script Language Reference Manual for more details on what str.tostring command is capable of. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).